# Do disabled button's children bubble?

Tags: javascript, button, event-handling, addeventlistener, event-bubbling

EDIT

I think this has to do with custom elements.  If I replace the button's child with a simple `<p>` we get the expected behavior (i.e. clicking on the child does not result in the parent's event handler being executed)

```
<div id="container">
  <button disabled>
    <p>X</p>
  <button>
</div>
```

---

Say I have the following:

```
<div id="container">
  <button disabled>
    <some-custom-element>
      < /* some svg stuff /* ></>
    </some-custom-element>
  <button>
</div>
```

say I have

```
$container = document.getElementById('container')
$container.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // stuff
})
```

If I click the BUTTON (like the very edge of it, so not the child), I do not end up in the button's parent's click listener.

But if I click the button's child, the event makes its way up to the button's parent, despite the button being disabled.  I had expected the propagation to stop at the disabled button but I don't really know why I expected that.

Is this expected?

Comment: That behavior would certainly surprise me.